# I Want to know how to use a save file

Tags: python, save, pickle

I am making a virtual pet game where I am using countdowns and functions for the mechanics. And I plan on making it possible for saving so it's not reset everytime you close it. I don't understand how to use the save file once you run 
                      pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
I don't know what "WB"does and means, and I don't know how to open up the Save.p and use the data to continue the game. Thanks in advance

Comment: wb means write to the file in binary mode

Comment: wb = **w**rite **b**inary, to **r**ead **b**inary use "rb"

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation for `open`?

Comment: Thank you for all of your help I think I understand more now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have nice explanation in this link:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm, please see the section **Syntax**.

To open the file again with pickle you need to code like this:

```
data = pickle.load(open("\path\filename.txt","r")) # For only read file
```

For appending the file use the mode "a", or appending and readind use "a+"

Answer (score 1):

The "wb" means "write bytes", because pickle.dump is widely used in order to open and write files with byte form. This makes the process of reading and writing such files more difficult, if you are not an experienced programmer. A easier way to manipulate files is to use the python keyword open(file, method) and then store it into a variable. Then, if you want to write you use write function or writeline. Else if you want to read, you must use read function or readline. You can make a search on internet and there are a lot of examples on that. I wish I helped you.